# Show a div and a table side by side

Tags: css

In the snippet below I want to put the *clear* button(hover inputs to show) by the right side of the table, align with the inputs, like this:

[image]

It is possible to achieve that without changing the current html structure? I have tried so many things but could not get it to work.

```js
$(".layer-lookup2").on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
 $(".clear-button")[(e.type == "mouseover" ? "show" : "hide")]();
});
```

```css
.layer-lookup2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.layer-lookup2 table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > div,
.layer-lookup2 span.k-widget {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > input {
    max-width: 50px;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > .label {
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > .label:hover,
.layer-lookup2 td > .label.hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.layer-lookup2 .clear-button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-lookup2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #1
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #2
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #3
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #4
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="clear-button"><button class="k-button">X</button></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/8pa8p98p/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Give your `.layer-lookup2` a `display: flex;` and `align-items: flex-end;`. You'll also need to add some padding to the button if you want it to be aligned with the inputs.

**CSS**

```
.layer-lookup2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.layer-lookup2 .clear-button {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pa8p98p/3/)**

Comment: It would be nice if the button could align with the inputs. Just added that in the question.

Comment: Answer has been updated. You'll need to apply some padding to the button for it to be centered.

Comment: I will keep yours, because it is easy to manipulate button's padding, since I didn't had much success with that with @j08691's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could float the table and add a little padding to your button:

```js
$(".layer-lookup2").on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
 $(".clear-button")[(e.type == "mouseover" ? "show" : "hide")]();
});
```

```css
.layer-lookup2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.layer-lookup2 table {
    table-layout: fixed;
  float:left;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > div,
.layer-lookup2 span.k-widget {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.layer-lookup2 td > input {
  max-width: 50px
}

.layer-lookup2 td > .label {
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer
}

.layer-lookup2 td > .label:hover,
.layer-lookup2 td > .label.hover {
    font-weight: bold
}

.layer-lookup2 .clear-button {
  display: none;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-lookup2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #1
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #2
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #3
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="label">
          Item #4
        </div>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="clear-button"><button class="k-button">X</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Adjusting to `padding-top:21px;` works like a charm.